# Pass data in header with express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I have a NodeJS app that I want to pass email into the header in my "main.hbs" when I register or log in. Maybe redirect should be different.

This is my register action:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
const { firstName, lastName, email, password, rePassword } = req.body;

const user = await authService.register({ firstName, lastName, email, password });
const token = authService.createToken(user);

res.cookie(sessionName, token);

res.redirect('/');
});
```

And this is my template:

```
<div id="box">
    {{#if error}}
    <div class="error-container">
        <p>{{error}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/if}}

    <nav>
        <!-- Do not forget to change the path to the image -->
        <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo">

        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts/all">All Posts</a></li>
            <!-- Logged users -->
            {{#if user}}
            <li><a href="/posts/create">Create Post</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts/user">Posts of {{email-of-user}}</a></li> // Here I want to pass my email
            <li><a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
            <!-- Guest users -->
            {{else}}
            <li><a href="/auth/register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
            {{/if}}
        </ul>

    </nav>


    <main>
        {{{body}}}
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In express you can pass an object to a page with **render** method
For example imagine if the details of user is in an object called currentUser in ther server then you can send the currentUser to page by

```
res.render('index', {currentUser});
```

later you can access the object in hbs file by simply by

```
  <p> {{currentUser.property}} </p>
```

Comment: I must redirect to home with logged user with email in the header.

Comment: Then in your home route add a logic to check whether a user is logged in already if yes then  pass user object to header . In the login or signup route after login you can redirect to home page

Comment: The logic you need must be added to the GET handler for the `/` route. You have not included this handler in your post. It will need to get the session token from the cookie, fetch the user, and then pass the user to the template in the `render` call.